# PHP CURL suddenly stop working on https request

Tags: php, curl, openshift

Until literally a couple of days ago, everything was going well, but now, Curl has stopped working for addresses with HTTPS.
This is the code:

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => array($registation_ids),
        'data'             => array( "message" => $message,
                                      "title"  => $title,
                                      "params" => $params,
                                      "code"   =>$code),
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This code had been running smoothly for over a year. But now it returns this:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET
>   /app/test_notifications.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at app-servername.rhcloud.com Port 80

However, if in the previous code I remove the `s` from `https:// ...` like this `http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` the request is sent without problems, but I can not allow that modification, since I also need access to other addresses that require SSL.

I have also tested with other `https` addresses, but it is the same result

Searching on the internet I found the solution to update curl, but I'm not sure if that is my solution, **since the code executed correctly https requests last week.** Anyway I leave here the `curl --version` response on my server:

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2  
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp  
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Is there a way to test that, in effect, is a Curl problem? That would help me to know how to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the problem and comparing my different applications in Openshift I realized that curl in https addresses worked in one of them. I checked the differences using **phpinfo()** and discovered that, contrary to what the server indicated, in the application that presented the problem, SSL Version was 3.18.1 and not 3.27.1.

**Solution:** restart the application in openshift and if that does not work, manually update curl. (Restart work for me)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a Google upgrade not a `Curl` problem.

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.
>   GCM Connection Server Reference
>   HTTP Protocol
>   XMPP Protocol
>   Android API Reference
>   iOS API Reference
>   Chrome API Reference
>   Contents
>   Downstream message syntax
>   Downstream HTTP messages (JSON)
>   Notification payload support
>   Downstream HTTP messages (Plain Text)
>   Interpreting a downstream message response
>   Downstream message error response codes

Check https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: I also thought that, but if I try to access paypal like this
$ch = curl_init(https://www.paypal.com/home); Also blocks it

Comment: Is there a way to test that, in effect, is a Curl problem?